# Something that is defined to be what it is is not part of the natural world. True?

Tags: definitions, environmental-philosophy

Numbers are defined as they are: 10 digits, a positional system, and all the arithmetic rules are defined to be what they are.

Even in all of math, many things are just defined to be what they are, like the fact that for exotic inputs of x, e to the x is a certain infinite series. This is a definition, not a theorem.

Is it true that, if something is defined to be what it is, then it is not part of the natural world?

Comment: [Definitions](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/definitions/) are linguistic entities: we define terms and concepts. BUT terms and concepts are used to describe the world.

Comment: Equator is defined to be "what it is" and it is part of the Earth, and e^x is often defined as the limit of its values at rational points, the infinite series is a theorem. Definitions are typically motivated and not just "what they are" for no reason, and it makes no difference whether what is defined is part of the natural world or an abstraction.

Answer (score 1):

Everything is what it is, so that doesn't do us any good.

All (useful) symbols are defined so as to represent ideas of things that they aren't. Nobody cares that a particular squiggle picture is the particular squiggle picture that it is. They care what *idea* that it *represents*.

To define (in the linguistic sense) is to associate a particular idea to a particular symbol. You can use whatever you want as a symbol, but only readily replicable symbols are useful. If I define a category of squiggle pictures that look like *NotPhilosophy* to mean the idea of you, then I can reproduce a squiggle picture every time I want to refer to you. If I define you, the physical human person, to mean the idea of a category of squiggle pictures, then I have to bonk you on the head, throw you over my shoulder, and wiggle you at somebody every time I want to use you as a symbol to refer to a squiggle picture that I could have just drawn anyway.

Relevant to the question, there are two broad kinds of ideas that symbols can be defined to represent:

- Abstract objects. These are the referents of ideas whose only associated processes are the processes that manifest the idea in consciousness (certain states of brains and/or souls) or store it for later retrieval by conscious minds (books, files, memories). For example, you can't really bite *the rules of basketball*. And insofar as you sort of can, you'd get a mouthful of the nervous system of a person trying to watch or play basketball, or a mouthful of paper or computer chips, not a mouthful of athletic equipment or lacquered wood. They exist, because the minds of people trying to watch or play basketball are obviously real - although whether minds are strictly part of the natural world or if they are also supernatural is a matter of debate. But if everybody suddenly forgot about them, and all the records were burned, there would be no process anywhere *doing* "being the rules of basketball" that you could even *sort of* go and bite. I think this is what you're trying to get at in your question.
- Concrete objects. These are the referents of ideas whose associated processes also include processes which do not manifest the idea in consciousness or store it for later retrieval by conscious minds. For example, you can really bite *a basketball*, and if you do, you'll get a mouthful of leather and rubber, not just somebody thinking about a leather and rubber sphere.

---

"Real, natural, physical," pffffffft. People drive themselves nuts by trying to use high prestige words with half-baked definitions. "Can you bite it, and where?" gets to the meat of the matter.

Answer (score 0):

> Something that is defined to be what it is is not part of the natural world. True?

False. **Generally, [natural and nature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nature) are taken to be anything that is not artificial**, the result of humanity's creative ability, and functions independently of people. For instance, mountains are not the work of people, so they are natural. Automobiles are the work of people, so they are not not natural. Philosophical distinctions might be drawn if one interjects into the conversation that people are a product of nature.

**[Definitions (SEP)](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/definitions/), are essentially linguistic descriptions of things.** Robinson, for instance, lumps all definitions in his taxonomy into two categories, real and lexical definitions. The former, which he tries to separate from the latter by emphasizing their role as specifying [necessary and sufficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necessity_and_sufficiency) criteria for existence, play an important role in philosophy. Lexical definitions on the other hand are records of how language is used conventionally.

**Accordingly, whether or not things have definitions does or does not make them natural, at least according to [scientific realism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_realism)**. Long before there were people and our definitions, on this view, there were atoms and trees and rocks and planets. Nature is simply an old word that goes back and captures the idea that the environment we are born into is largely independent of us and our existence and largely outside of our control.